# How can I get the distance in pixels between two points on the map, before/during zoom?

Tags: android, dictionary

I need to calculate what the distance in pixels between two points on a map will be after a zoom event.  My problem is that the projection gives inconsistent results while the map is zooming.

The calculation is simple:

```
Projection p = mapView.getProjection();
Point p1 = new Point();
Point p2 = new Point();
GeoPoint g1 = //value1
GeoPoint g2 = //value2
p.toPixels(g1, p1);
p.toPixels(g2, p2);
double distancePx = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
```

I detect a zoom in my `dispatchDraw` method of my MapView.  If I do the calculation right then I get inconsistent and weird results.  If I wait half a second and try that calculation, I get perfect results.  That's a little late though, as I really need to know the answer before I finish zooming.  Ideally I'd be able to figure out the distance in pixels based solely on the zoomLevel.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hrm can you scale your distance according to the zoom level? So if your at 150% zoom, scale your distancePx by that much?

Comment: I figured it wouldn't be, but it was worth a try :)